# Serialize object property with JMSSerializerBundle on entity

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

when I serialize my object using jmsserializerbundle I get corrent JSON object but one property is empty (it's object type), the definition of this property looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var stdObject
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="searchQueryParams", type="object")
 * @Expose
 * @Type("stdClass")
 */
private $searchQueryParams;
```

But even if there is an object on this entity the serializer outpus it like this:

`{
        "id": 10,
        "search_query_params": {},
        "created": "2013-07-02T10:31:02+0200"
    },`

Just an empty object, with is not true. This is value of searchQueryParams in DB:

`O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Greacja2";s:10:"price_from";s:4:"2000";}`

Answer (score 0):

Its a well-known [bug](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/158) of jms serializer. You can store data in database as array and serialize later as array.

Answer (score 0):

Changing @Type to "Array" seemed to worked.